# How to keep MongoDB connection alive for a user until he/she leaves the site nextjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I'm using `Nextjs` and `MongoDB` to create a full-stack portfolio website, `insert, find, update, delete, ...` is fine but for everything I want to do I need to create a new connection whit MongoDB.

I create a `models` folder inside the project root directory. in the model folder, I have a `model.js` class file inside that I wrote my connection query:

model.js code:

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

    class Model {
      constructor(collectionName) {
        this.collectionName = collectionName;
      }
    
      async getDb() {
        try {
          const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.dbUri);
    
          const db = client.db();
    
          return db.collection(this.collectionName);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("Model", err);
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }
    
    export default Model;
```

and in the `models` folder, I have another class model named `skills.js`

skills.js code:

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
import Model from "./model";

class Skills extends Model {
  constructor(id, title, slug, rate) {
    super("skills");
    this._id = id ? id : null;
    this.title = title ? title : null;
    this.rate = rate ? rate : null;
    this.slug = slug ? slug : null;
    this.created_at = new Date().valueOf();
    this.updated_at = new Date().valueOf();
  }

  async save() {
    const db = await this.getDb();

    if (db) {
      try {
        const data = await db.insertOne({
          title: this.title,
          slug: this.slug,
          skillRate: this.rate,
          created_at: this.created_at,
          updated_at: this.updated_at,
        });

        return data.acknowledged;
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }

  async all() {
    const db = await this.getDb();
    if (db) {
      try {
        const data = await db.find({}).toArray();
        return data;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Skill model", err);
        throw err;
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("db notfound");
    }
  }

  async getOne() {
    const db = await this.getDb();

    if (db) {
      try {
        const data = await db.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(this._id) });

        return data;
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }

  async update() {
    const db = await this.getDb();

    if (db) {
      try {
        const data = await db.updateOne(
          { _id: ObjectId(this._id) },
          {
            $set: {
              title: this.title,
              slug: this.slug,
              skillRate: this.rate,
              updated_at: this.updated_at,
            },
          }
        );

        return data;
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }

  async getDeleteOne() {
    const db = await this.getDb();

    if (db) {
      try {
        const result = await db.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(this._id) });

        const data = await db.find({}).toArray();

        return data;
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
}

export default Skills;
```

I call `Skill class` from `api/test.js` route folder:

test api code:

```
    import slugMaker from "../../../../helpers/slug-maker";
import Skills from "../../../../models/skills";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { id } = req.query;
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    const skill = new Skills();
    skill._id = id;
    try {
      const data = await skill.getOne();

      return res.status(200).json({ message: "fetch successful.", data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("find", err);
    }
  } else if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { title, skillRate } = req.body;

    const slug = slugMaker(title);

    const skill = new Skills();
    skill._id = id;
    skill.title = title;
    skill.slug = slug;
    skill.rate = skillRate;

    try {
      const result = await skill.update();

      return res
        .status(201)
        .json({ message: "تغییرات با موفقیت اعمال شد.", result });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  } else {
    return res
      .status(405)
      .json({ message: "Only POST or GET request supported for this route." });
  }
}
```

I noticed for every request I made a new connection and get limited by MongoDB, I need to create one connection for every user visiting the site and keep it until he/she leaves the site.

is that possible, and how do I do this?

Comment: why do you need a connection per client and not connect once for the app?

Comment: exactly I need a connection per app,

Comment: Ok so just connect this once when the application launches instead?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert yes, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: you cannot. we discussed it on discord the other day. They recommended to use data-api  for atlas, or write your own for self-hosted mongo.  In my opinion it will kill performance if you have consecutive queries due to http latency, but at least it solve the problem with number of open connections.